# Intellisense in Access 2019

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, module, intellisense

Hello all (excuse me please if I am in the wrong forum)

I have just bought MS Office Professional 2019 and am using Access 2019.

Previous versions of Access came with "intellisense" (is this what it is called?) which would highlight errors in my VBA code in a module "on the fly". That is, if I wrote a line of code that had syntax errors, the errors in the line would be highlighted. This does not seem to be switched on (or available at all) in the new Access 2019.

I have spent days looking for an answer to this, so you are my last hope. Am I missing a reference file or something?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Just to add, ticking "Auto Syntax check" checkbox in the "tools options" does not work and makes no difference. No syntax errors are highlighted either way.

Comment: Also, none of the options in the "tools options" dialog box work. "Require Variable Declaration", when checked, does NOT produce an error for undeclared variables.

Comment: General for all VBA code: Always use Option Explicit in all code files to guard from undeclared variables (eg. misspelled)

Answer (score 1):

**Require Variable Declaration** checked causes `Option Explicit` line to automatically generate in header of newly created VBA module. It does not itself cause compiler to look for undeclared variables - `Option Explicit` does that. For existing modules without this line, it will have to be manually added. Why MS did not make this option checked by default is a mystery.

**Auto List Members** unchecked disables intellisense. When checked, intellisense should work if appropriate libraries are active. Early binding must be used for declaring and setting object variables. Intellisense is not really a syntax checker, it is an aid to constructing code but does not prevent incorrect construction.

**Auto Syntax Check** has nothing to do with provoking intellisense. Even when unchecked, syntax errors are red highlighted, such as not using line continuation character where needed. What doesn't happen is a popup notification of error.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I suppose I was hoping that "Require Variable Declaration" would highlight this "on the fly" rather than just compiling. Regards my other query, I have searched back to earlier versions of access and every version, going right back my Windows 97 machine (which still runs perfectly - good old Dell), the "Auto Syntax Check" does nothing. Does it work on your machine? Are you getting a red highlight? I know it does this in Visual Studio. But it doesn't work for me at all on Access and although others might find it a pain, I think it would be a cool addition to my modern lifestyle!

Comment: @June7: Regarding `Option Explicit` you mean modules, not procedures, I guess? ;-)

Comment: I think I actually have something really screwed up in my VBA editor. I need help! For example, if I refer to a control that doesn't exist in the "OnCurrent" event, not only does VBA editor not tell me there is no control of that name in the forms collection, but the form will not open AND, no error is notified to me at all (it doesn't break for editing on the offending line. So I am writing code now without ANY help. If I get anything wrong, VBA gives me no clue as to where. Clearly, I haven't got my settings properly set. Can anyone advise?

Comment: This is not a code issue so there is nothing to analyze. Issue is not reproducible so really not appropriate for SO. I have never heard of this. Perhaps try removing and reinstalling Access.

Comment: I tested the scenario. When opening form I get popup message that control does not exist which I OK then debugger highlights the procedure and then I quit the debugger and form is already open anyway. Then when I try to click in any control on form, the message pops again. Have to right click and close form or switch to design view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you everyone for your replies. The option settings suggested seem to be working now (intellisense will only look for syntax errors in known procedures or methods - if you type general rubbish there is no syntax to correct. It only does so much for you!). As to the debugger failing to break on an error, I seemed to have had the "USE ACCESS SPECIAL KEYS" checkbox (OPTIONS > CURRENT DATABASE >) unchecked, and this stopped the debugger from breaking on an error (amongst other VBA tools also denied).